# Instant validation of a form in my jsp

Tags: javascript, forms, jsp

I am using j2EE structure , so all my the actions o my forms are directed to servlet ..
My problem is when I want to make an instant validation of my form field by field 
I have to use script.php(to connect to database) which must be on the action of my form (but I can't delete action="servletName" ).

Comment: I don't mean to sound rude, but how are we supposed to give you any advice with what you've given us? We have no code to go off of, and "instant validation" is very broad. Please include your attempt.

Comment: My jsp works fine , I have a login form which I had to validate the login and password. While I am using servlet if login and password are correct resp.sendRedirect("index.jsp"); else resp.sendRedirect("loginPage.jsp"); , how can I inform the user that his login and password are incorrect using some css style . all I need is an idea

Comment: You're connecting to the db with a script.php in JSP?  Now I've seen everything.  As RUJordan said, this question can't be answered as presented.

Comment: no, if the user writes his login I wanna check if it exists on db !        I am using j2ee , my form is on the jsp page <form action="servletLogin" method="post"> <input type="text" id="login" name="login" /> <input type="submit" value="connect"/></form>

Comment: I guess I found it , am gonna use the URL of my webService method to get the result in script.js

Answer (score -1):

Establishing a database connection is a key task in making JSP work.  Review instructions about topics like Tomcat server.  It sounds like you need some more basic research in order to get your first JSP programs operational.

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/ssl-howto.html

Comment: Sorry But you didn't get what I mean!

Comment: My jsp works fine , I have a login form which I had to validate the login and password. While I am using servlet if login and password are correct resp.sendRedirect("index.jsp"); else  resp.sendRedirect("loginPage.jsp"); , how can I inform the user that his login and password are incorrect using some css style . all I need is an idea

Comment: This does not seem to answer the question at all.

Comment: The question is not at all clear, so no answer can be given. Certainly this doesn't answer it.